# What is the easiest way to add additional html to my form using the Orbeon Form Builder?

Tags: html, orbeon

We want to use Orbeon Forms to build and run some forms, however these forms require some more explaining than is possible in the 'hint' or 'help' sections. ('hint' is supposed to be rather short, 'help' does not support any kind of formatting, as far as i can tell) Therefore, I'd like to put some HTML above or below some of the questions (controls).

Now, I know that there is an option that shows you the source and allows you to make changes. This is, however, quite complex for a non-technical person.

Is there a(nother) way of inserting pieces of HTML in a form?

Also, I have looked at ways of creating a control that outputs/shows HTML, however it seems that both XBL and the Java classes for XForms controls always assume that it should be bound to some variable that's also in the resulting XML document. (And I'd rather not have that, since it will just be clarifying text.) Though it could be that I overlooked another possible option in XBL or Java.

Is it possible to create a component that does not get bound to the XML instance? (That I can then use to create a control that provides HTML functionality.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For HTML in help message, Form Builder supports form authors entering a help message as HTML since version 4.4.
- We often get requests for a control allowing form authors to enter their own HTML from Form Builder, this isn't yet implemented, at the point of this writing, and we have an RFE ([#507](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/507)) to cover this.

Comment: This is an interesting option. I haven't tried it yet, however it seems like a small enough modification that it is possible to explain this to a non-technical person, or maybe let them request the change after the form is finished.
Is there any chance of this ending up in the Form Builder as a feature. Maybe an option to switch between text-only and HTML help text, or at least that the XForms engine understands this construct?

Comment: As I write this, it isn't a feature we have planned to implement for the next release. But it isn't a large feature either, so it is something that could get done if we get this as a request from a client with a Development Support plan, or someone in the community contributes an implementation for this feature.